# Android, How to put an ArrayList<myObject> in an Intent?

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist, android-intent

I have two Activities, in the first one, I instanciate an ArrayList of Object myObject. In the second activity, i need to get this Arraylist. I don't know how to do that with an intent ?

(Object is a class I have created)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make your Object class implement [Parcelabel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) you can pack your arraylist into the bundle you send with the intent

see [this link](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html) for an example

Comment: Thank you getekha, it almost works. I have a problem with one element of my object. It's a list of object of another class i've implemented. I've read in your example, that i need to use "readList(listInstance, .class.getClassLoader());", but I get a nullpointer exception on the line. I just want to know how exactly i need to write this.

Comment: You will have to make your other class parcelabel as well and pack it with writeTypedList

Answer (score 1):

Usually you use [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) objects to pass information between Activities, but these only allow for simple type objects. Typically, for passing more complex object types you generally have to construct a static context of some kind and set your values on that, which is then available to the second activity. It feels dirty, but I've got over it in my apps now.

Comment: ArrayList<String> can be sent using bundle

Comment: He's specifically stated he wants to send an ArrayList of his own objects, not Strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `myObject` will have to implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). Then, you can use [putParcelableArrayListExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29) from your intent to pass it to the next activity and retrieve the list with [getParcelableArrayListExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

I used like this.

**put:**

```
intent.putExtra("data", new DataWrapper(selectedTasks));
startActivity(intent);
```

**get:**

```
DataWrapper dw = (DataWrapper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
ArrayList<SelectedTask> taskList = dw.getList();
```

Arraylist object should be Serializable

```
public class SelectedTask implements Serializable{

}

public class DataWrapper implements Serializable{
    private ArrayList<SelectedTask> slist;

       public DataWrapper(ArrayList<SelectedTask> data) {
          this.slist = data;
       }

       public ArrayList<SelectedTask> getList() {
          return this.slist;
       }
}
```